# Where in the database is the note field for contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, database

One can enter notes with a new contribution and they show up like this:

> **Campaign**   Middleport Pottery, Steam Engine
>
> **Receipt Sent**   April 10th, 2015 10:56 AM
>
> **Note**   ***Where is the note field?***
>
> **Transaction ID** 101010

And are in the template like this:

```
{if $receipt_date}          
  <tr>          
            <td class="label">{ts}Receipt Sent{/ts}</td>
            <td>{$receipt_date|crmDate}</td>
    </tr>          
  {/if}

{foreach from=$note item="rec"}          
  {if $rec }          
    <tr>          
      <td class="label">{ts}Note{/ts}</td>       
      <td>{$rec}</td>             //LINE IN QUESTION!
    </tr>          
  {/if}          
{/foreach}


  {if $trxn_id}          
    <tr>          
      <td class="label">{ts}Transaction ID{/ts}</td>          
      <td>{$trxn_id}</td>          
    </tr>          
  {/if}
```

However it seems I can not export the data in this field from the user interface and I can not seem to find it in the database to create a query. Any idea on table and field?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

civicrm_note

entity_table = 'civicrm_contribution'

entity_id = contributionID

Answer (score 6):

You can retrieve contribution notes via the api using:

```
civicrm_api3('Note', 'get', array(
  'entity_table' => 'civicrm_contribution',
  'entity_id' => $contributionID,
));
```

Or see the api explorer to generate this in other formats (you can also do it from within a smarty template, for example).

**Important:** The api returns raw, unsanitized user input. If you are displaying this value, be sure to *sanitize the output* using `htmlspecialchars` or similar.